# hay una manera mas rapida que el picturebox c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, picturebox

estoy tratando de mejorar el performance de las imágenes ya que cuando abro un formulario hijo, las imágenes de este al principio aparecen con lo que tenia el formulario padre atrás y después ya si se pone la imagen que va, ese es el típico comportamiento de cuando la aplicación esta lenta.

Este es el código que le puse a la imagen que mas se usa.

```
private void games_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Visible = false;
    if (gl == null)
    {
        gl = new exilum_gam.galeria();
        gl.MdiParent = this;
        gl.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(cerrar);
        gl.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        gl.Activate();
    }
}
```

Me gustaría saber si hay una mejor manera para desplegar imágenes que el picturebox o que ese comportamiento de el picturebox mostrando lo que había detrás y después que cargue bien la imagen no se note.

Comment: ¿Cuántas imágenes son las que cargas?¿que tamaño tienen las imágenes?puedes incluir la implementación del constructor y form_Load de la clase galeria.

Comment: Tiene 8 imagenes, una de fondo y las otras picturebox, size promedio es 150x110(picturebox) pero si te refieres a peso es poco en promedio es 28 kb y la imagen de fondo es 78Kb,  el constructor solo tiene initializecomponent() no he agregado nada, ni tampoco evento load, lo que tengo es en los picturebox es para abrir los juegos, Ejemplo:

  private void atrapa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FeedMEWER atrapa = new FeedMEWER();
            atrapa.ShowDialog();
        }

Comment: Ya estoy pensando agregar las imágenes con GDI+ a ver si así esta mucho mas rapido